Collected "Praise" in Personal user chats
I have a script written via Power Automate that collects and collects Prise sent to each other in "Command" in Teams and displays it all in SharePoint, is there a trigger for Power Automate so that it works in personal chats of all users located in our MS 365?
I would like to collect these Praises that users send to each other in personal chats, and not just in some team, is there a similar script and what rights/what account should be connected to this script in order to be able to track it.

Currently, Power Automate does not have a direct trigger for personal chats in Microsoft Teams. The triggers available are generally for team channels and group chats. However, you can use the Microsoft Graph API to access messages in personal chats,

Is there any guide on how to implement my idea?

Please refer to the documents below for the Graph API to access messages in personal chats.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
2.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chats-getallmessages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
3.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http


Currently, Power Automate does not have a direct trigger for personal chats in Microsoft Teams. The triggers available are generally for team channels and group chats. However, you can use the Microsoft Graph API to access messages in personal chats
Please refer to the documents below for the Graph API to access messages in personal chats.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chats-getallmessages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
